# How to get the value of a cell across all worksheets

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I'm trying to write a VBScript function that collects the value of a cell ("E1") across all tabs of an Excel document into an array (Reviewers).

I wrote the following code, but the data is not being stored into the array, can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

This is the code:

[image: vba screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I can't see your code as my company has blocked access to imageshack.

Have you tried something like the following?

```
Dim i As Long
Dim reviewers() As String
ReDim reviewers(0 To Worksheets.Count - 1)

For i = 0 To Worksheets.Count - 1
    reviewers(i) = Worksheets(i + 1).Cells(1, 5).Value
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Or even, since Worksheets is 1-based (so we can lose that +1 and -1 business):

```
Dim i As Long
Dim reviewers() As String
ReDim reviewers(1 To Worksheets.Count)

For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count 
    reviewers(i) = Worksheets(i).Cells(1, 5).Value
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code says

```
 Reviewers(N) = Sheets(N+1).Range("B7:C7").Value
```

Range B7:C7 consists of two cells, not one, and therefore the value is an array, not a single value. Use a range of one cell.

Answer (score 0):

You just need concatenate the cells if you want them both in there or replace the & with + if you want to add them, I don't know if they are values or text.

```
Reviewers(N) = Sheets(N+1).Range("B7").Value & Sheets(N+1).Range("C7").Value
```